# Nintex Regular expression Pattern regex extract filename

Tags: regex, sharepoint, workflow

May I know how could I extract the Company name without the from the file extension example

`CompanyName_PF_BILL_FY2015`

to

`CompanyName`

using regex? been using `(?<=_).*` but it does seem to work.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The pattern to match the company name is missing.

I am not sure what the makeup of company name actually is but assuming it is a single word without special characters you could use:

```
(?<=[A-Z,a-z]+)_.*
```

Note you most likely want the underscore outside the bracketed group so it is not included at the end of the company name.

I am also not totally sure of the reason for the use of '?<=' (Zero-width positive lookbehind assertion).

Normally I try to keep it simple by using an anchor for the start of the string '^', followed by one or more word characters '[A-Z,a-z]+' followed by the underscore '_' as follows:

```
^([A-Z,a-z]+)_.*
```

Comment: Hi Glen, thank you for your tips. However when i tried  `(?<=\w+)_.* ` on http://regexstorm.net/tester it only extract _PF_BILL_FY2015 instead of CompanyName from `CompanyName_PF_BILL_FY2015` .. Please help thanks!!

Comment: Turns out \w also matches '_' so '[A-Z,a-z]' is needed to only match letters.  You will need to check that companyname can only contain letters otherwise any additional characters will need to be added.  Check out the "Split List" tab on the output of Regexstorm to see the groupings extracted.  The green highlighting shows the entire match not what you are looking for in the '()'.